# Selenium WD Python Message: Invalid timeout type specified: sessionId

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

Hi I'm new here and in automating tests area.
I want to automate simple case like "login" on the different browsers.
For Chrome it works:

```
from selenium import webdriver
# start a new Chrome session
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait( 10 )
driver.maximize_window()
# navigate to the test platform
driver.get( "https://xxxxxxxxx.com" )
# insert password
password = driver.find_element_by_id( "password" )
password.send_keys( "123123" )
driver.find_element_by_class_name( "primaryBtn" ).click()
# driver.implicitly_wait( 20 )
driver.quit()
```

but when I am trying to do it for IE unfortunately i get:
*selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: Invalid timeout type specified: sessionId*

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver

dir = os.path.dirname( __file__ )

ie_driver_path = dir + "\IEDriverServer.exe"
driver = webdriver.Ie()
driver.implicitly_wait( 30 )
driver.maximize_window()
# navigate to the test platform
driver.get( "https://xxxxxxxxxxxx.com" )
# insert password
password = driver.find_element_by_id( "password" )
password.send_keys( "xxxxxxxx" )
driver.find_element_by_class_name( "primaryBtn" ).click()
driver.quit()
```

Could anybody give me some tips/suggestions what is important in this case and what should I do next?
thank you from the mountain :P

Answer (score 1):

I know it's more than a year later but this for everyone that may come acrosss this issue.. the solution i found was using the 3.4 version of the selenium driver.

That did the trick